# Exim4 mailer daemon address

Tags: email-server, exim

My exim4 mail server sends notification using the wrong extension, I mean:

```
Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@mydomain.err>
```

This server is a multi-domain server and mydomain.err is one of managed domains but not the main one. I would like to set the main domain and the daemon address but I cannot find it in the configuration, I did a grep in all exim configuration looking for mydomain.err and I find it only here:

```
dc_other_hostnames='maindomain.com;mydomain.err;otherdomain.com'
```

Where can I change the daemon address and the main domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you want is `qualify_domain`.  Depending on your configuration this may be read from `/etc/mailname`.

Comment: I found this note:  If MAIN_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME_AS_QUALIFY_DOMAIN is defined, the primary
# hostname is used. If not, but MAIN_QUALIFY_DOMAIN is set, the value
# of MAIN_QUALIFY_DOMAIN is used. If both macros are not defined,
# the first line of /etc/mailname is used.